# Gaussian elimination problem

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

$$x_1 + 10x_2 − 3x_3 = 8$$

$$x_1 + 10x_2 + 2x_3 = 13$$

$$x_1 + 4x_2 + 2x_3 = 7$$

**when making 2nd and 3rd 1st columns 0 using Gaussian elimination, the second row second column also becomes zero, so then i cant have a diagonal set of ones in the matrix. 
What do?**

Thanks in advance, i appreciate your intelligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting $$\pmatrix{1&10&-3\\0&0&5\\0&-6&5}$$ , simply swap the
second and the third row and continute the algorithm.